# MutableList not adding new values Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, mutablelist

I am getting list of file's path from a specific folder, but when I try to add it in my mutable list, the list remains empty.

```
var filePath: MutableList<String>? = null
val path = File(getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES).path, "BacFo Camera")
if (path.exists()) {
    for(i in path.list().iterator()){
        filePath?.add("" + path.toString() + "/" + i)  //here i=file name
    }
}
```

After running Debugger the values does come in variable `i` but some how the mutable list remain empty. I am new to Kotlin, Please help!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You declared your MutableList but initialized it with `null`. So the variable is reserved but is not initialized with a list.

When you try to add a value to the List, you use a [safe call](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html#safe-calls) `?.` that is only executed, when the value (your list) is not `null`. But actually it is `null` to the call is not executed.

You should initialize your List e.g. with an `ArrayList`.

```
var filePath: MutableList<String>? = ArrayList<String>()
```

As you always initialize your List now, you can even use the `val` instead of `var` and can get rid of the save call:

```
val filePath: MutableList<String>? = ArrayList<String>()
val path = File(getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES).path, "BacFo Camera")
if (path.exists()) {
    for(i in path.list().iterator()){
        filePath.add("" + path.toString() + "/" + i)  //here i=file name
    }
}
```

Answer (score 12):

> the list remains empty.

No, the list is `null`:

```
var filePath :MutableList<String> ?=null
```

Try assigning it a value:

```
var filePath: MutableList<String> = mutableListOf()
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
var filePath: MutableList<String> = arrayListOf()
```

Comment: Could you please explain why this solves the OP's problem

Comment: @Kingsley, this solves the problem because you initialize the mutable list as a list in which you can add new values ​​and change its content dynamically. (https://www.javatpoint.com/kotlin-arraylist-arraylistof)